# Удаленный перезапуск службы

Tags: windows, служба

На удаленной машине "x" запущена служба "у". Как с машины "z", перезапустить службу "y" на машине "x"?

Answer (score 1):

Используя [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/bb897553):

```
@echo offpsexec \\X cmd "/c net stop Y"psexec \\X cmd "/c net start Y"
```

Answer (score 1):

А с помощью консоли управления? Забыли чтоли? "Мой компьютер" правой кнопкой мыши, выбрать управление. Первую строку (Управление компьютером (локально)) щёлкнуть правой кнопкой мыши и выбрать "Подключиться к другому компьютеру". Ввести адрес удаленного компа. В случае если нет проблем с правами доступа к компу получите доступ в том числе и к разделу "Службы и приложения" удаленного компьютера. И на здоровье перезапускайте службы хоть по 50 раз

Answer (score 0):

На удаленной машине система какая стоит? Вообще, есть на это putty для линукса и удалённый рабочий стол для windows.

Answer (score 0):

ubuntu:

```
ssh login@159.255.30.12(ip) - соединение с удаленным X ...sudo /etc/init.d/(имя службы) restart - перезагрузка службы Y
```